# Python tweepy - search keyword then reply

Tags: python, python-3.3, tweepy

I want to do the following:

1) search a word (example : "dog")
2) reply (mention) those users how have just tweeted a tweet with the word "dog"

This is how far I got:

```
import tweepy

consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

tweetId = tweet['results'][0]['id']

api.update_status('My status update',tweetId)
```

I'm getting an error message "tweet is not defined".

I don't understand that and where do I get the tweetId from?

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: What type of tweets you want to reply to ? are these tweets that pop on your timeline or you want to globally search the tweets , and the the code you have provided is incomplete you must be missing some line I guess, cross check it with the source

Answer (score 0):

Your 'tweet' variable has no value so your trying to get a tweetId from something that you have not yet assigned. Use one of these API calls http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.2.0/getting_started.html and you should be actually able to retrieve tweets.

For example to access tweets on a users home page:

```
public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print tweet.text
```

You should then do some research on your own to try and find out how to search this data.